# Which one of the following is/are correct?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, examples-counterexamples

> Which one of the following statements is/are correct?
>
> $(a)$ Every bounded continuous real valued function on $\mathbb Q^2$ can be extended to a bounded continuous function on $\mathbb R^2.$
>
> $(b)$ There exists a non-finite subset $X$ of $\mathbb Q^2$
> such that every real valued continuous function on $X$ is bounded.

For $(a)$ I am thinking of a counter-example which is the following $:$

Consider the function $f : \mathbb Q^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 2 & x \gt \sqrt 2 \\ 1 & x \lt \sqrt 2 \end{cases}$$ Then $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb Q^2$ but it has no continuous extension on $\mathbb R^2.$ So $(a)$ is definitely false. But I have no idea as to how to approach $(b).$ Any suggestion will be a boon for me at this stage.

Thanks for investing your valuable time in reading my question.

Comment: Try $X=\{1,1/2,1/3,\dots\}\cup\{0\}$.

Comment: @David C. Ullrich do you mean to say $$X=\{(1,0),(1/2,0),(1/3,0),...\}\cup \{(0,0)\}$$ or something similar?

Comment: of course......

Comment: If there exists a real-valued continuous function on $X$ which is unbounded (let's say unbounded above) then there exists a sequence $\{(x_n,0)\}_{n \geq 1}$ in $X$ of infinitely many terms such that $f(x_n,0) \to \infty.$ Since $X$ is compact the sequence has a convergent subsequence in $X.$ But the only possible limit of any convergent sequence in $X$ having infinitely many terms is $(0,0).$ Which implies by continuity of $f$ that $f(0,0) = \infty.$ Is that what you meant to say @David C. Ullrich?

Comment: So it turns out to me that any non-empty compact subset of $\mathbb Q^2$ would work. Isn't it so?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Comment: Yes, in fact if I'd known you knew about compactness I would have just said any (infinite) compact subset of $\Bbb Q^2$ would work, for example a convergent sequence plus its limit.